# Spring security acl and Postgres

Tags: grails, spring-security-acl

Using "spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1" as a Grails plugin with an application linked to a Postgres 9.3 data source, the following bug happens at startup:

```
.. finished configuring Spring Security ACL
2013-12-19 13:20:19,588 ERROR [GrailsContextLoader] - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'webExpressionVoter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'webExpressionHandler' while setting bean property 'expressionHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webExpressionHandler': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'permissionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'permissionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'permissionEvaluator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webExpressionVoter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'webExpressionHandler' while setting bean property 'expressionHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webExpressionHandler': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'permissionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'permissionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'permissionEvaluator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webExpressionHandler': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'permissionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'permissionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'permissionEvaluator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'permissionEvaluator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
    ... 4 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: aclCache Cache: Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory.getDataFile(DiskOverflowStorageFactory.java:81)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory.<init>(DiskOverflowStorageFactory.java:73)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.impl.OverflowToDiskStore.create(OverflowToDiskStore.java:63)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.initialise(Cache.java:1113)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheNoCheck(CacheManager.java:1100)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCache(CacheManager.java:1006)
    ... 4 more
```

- Tested with or without "cache 1.1.1" activated, same result
- No issue with mysql
- Env: grails 2.3.4

A JIRA ticket will be open in the coming days if no workaround found by myself or any contributor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconfigure the bean in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` to not overflow to disk:

```
beans = {
   ehcacheAclCache(EhCacheFactoryBean) {
      cacheManager = ref('aclCacheManager')
      cacheName = 'aclCache'
      overflowToDisk = false
   }
}
```